# Where to insert "WHERE"-condition into SQL-statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL, which is working just fine:

```
"SELECT t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance FROM db1 t JOIN (SELECT tt.date, MAX(tt.time) as 'maxtime' FROM db1 tt GROUP BY tt.date) m ON m.maxtime = t.time AND t.date = m.date"
```

What I would like now is to insert a WHERE condition, to only include data from specific dates. Specifically, I want to use `WHERE date >= '$dateSelect'`. I am not quite sure where I have to insert this condition into the query to make it work - I have tried several locations already (always behind the `FROM db1` parts) but have not made it work yet.

Can anyone help me out? Very much appreciate the help!

Comment: where should be at the end of the query, in case of subquery it will be the last part of that subquery, in addition `where clause` should be before `group by`, `order by` and `limit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an inner join, this `where` clause could be applied either to the top level query or the inner query. Personally, I'd apply it to **both** of them. In the worst case, it clutters up the code a bit. In the best case, you gain the ability to apply additional filtering before joining the two results the optimizer may have missed otherwise:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance 
FROM   db1 t 
JOIN   (SELECT   tt.date, MAX(tt.time) as 'maxtime' 
        FROM     db1 tt 
        WHERE    tt.date >= '$dateSelect' -- Here
        GROUP BY tt.date) m ON m.maxtime = t.time AND t.date = m.date
WHERE  t.date >= '$dateSelect' -- And here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance 
FROM db1 t 
JOIN (
    SELECT tt.date, MAX(tt.time) as 'maxtime' 
    FROM db1 tt GROUP BY tt.date
    ) m ON (m.maxtime = t.time AND t.date = m.date)
WHERE t.date >= '$dateSelect'
```

Answer (score 0):

As per principle, at University, I always learnt that this should be set as the following:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Therefore an SQL sample statement would be this:

```
SELECT studentNo, class, AVG(marks) AS avgMarks, subjects FROM Students
WHERE age > 18
GROUP BY class
HAVING COUNT(subjects) > 5
ORDER BY avgMarks DESC
```

This would return the details for students in a typical school who are older than 18 years of age, taking classes in more than 5 subjects, grouping them by the class they are in and ordering the results output by the average mark of each student.